# Compound spelling rules for composites of prepositions and nouns

Tags: preposition, spelling, adverb, reformed-orthography

The compound spelling rules below explicitly state **zu Fuß** and interdict an alternative. Is this coherent with the rules? I consider **zu Fuß** as adverbial. E.g. *Er geht immer zu Fuß*, thus it should be possible to write the term together.

> **Präposition (Verhältniswort) und Substantiv**
>
> **Regel 63:**
>
> Man schreibt ein [verblasstes] Substantiv mit einer Präposition
>   zusammen, wenn die Fügung zu einer neuen Präposition oder einem Adverb
>   geworden ist. In vielen Fällen kann die Fügung auch als Wortgruppe
>   angesehen und getrennt geschrieben werden <§ 39 (1) und (3), E3 (1)
>   und (3)>.
>
> - anstatt, inmitten, zuliebe
> - anstelle oder an Stelle
> - aufgrund oder auf Grund
> - infrage oder in Frage [stellen, kommen]
> - zugrunde oder zu Grunde [gehen, richten]
>     aufseiten oder auf Seiten
>
> aber nur getrennt: zu Fuß, zu Ende, von Sinnen, bei der Hand
>   <sup>1</sup>

What is the explanation for this?

---

<sup>Taken from: http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/getrennt-und-zusammenschreibung</sup>

Comment: The title and the first sentence are misleading, for your question does not have to do anything with hyphens (Bindestrichen). See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen

Comment: I am not sure why you think *in adverbial usage* should mean you can write "zu Fuß" as one word. *... man schreibt getrennt ... Fälle, in denen Wortart, Wortform oder die Bedeutung einzelner Bestandteile deutlich erkennbar ist ... **Fügungen in adverbialer Verwendung** ... zu Fuß [gehen] ...*. You stopped reading §39 too early.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich I actually searched a while for a term equivalent to *Zusammen- und Getrenntschreibung*. I saw the use of (un)coupled and separated, but not often and also hyphenation (rules). If you know a appropriate translation and have sources, I'll gladly change it.

Comment: @tofro I did not read §39. What I've read is above, I also included a link.

Comment: Das Problem mit der Überschrift hättest Du nicht gehabt, wenn Du die Frage auf Deutsch gestellt hättest.

Comment: Then you should. Compound spelling is a bit of an obscure topic in German, but §39 of the "Rechtschreibregeln" is pretty clear about the exceptions.

Comment: @mike: _Separate or compound spelling_ is what you are looking for.

Comment: @mike: Du hast die Möglichkeit, deine Frage (samt Überschrift) zu editieren. Wenn du die fremdsprachigen Teile durch deutsche Texte ersetzt, dann muss du nicht mühsam nach halbwegs passenden englischen Vokabeln suchen. Wir Antwortautoren, die wir (fast) alle deutsche Muttersprachler mit teils durchwachsenen Englischkenntnissen sind (siehe https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1261/1487), müssen nicht herumraten, was mit dem englischen Geschwafel gemeint sein könnte, und in Zukunft kriegt du als Antwort auch keine Übersetzungen ins Englische mehr.

Answer (score 1):

The important part of this rule is: *wenn die Fügung zu einer neuen Präposition oder einem Adverb **geworden ist**.*

So, the rule says: *if such a preposition/such an adverb **exists**, you write it as such, in one word.*

And then it says: *In vielen Fällen kann die Fügung auch als Wortgruppe angesehen und getrennt geschrieben werden.*

So, the rule says: *but in many cases you may also write it in two words.*

And then there are some examples given in which there is no combined preposition/adverb available (yet).

---

So, basically, this rule boils down to: *it's irregular, learn it one by one, sorry for the inconvenience.*

Comment: Danke, aber ich habe nicht nach einer Übersetzung gefragt. Und ausgehend von *neue Präposition* ein *exists* zu folgern, finde ich ziemlich gewagt.

Comment: Warum stellst du deine Frage auf Englisch, wenn du Deutsch sprichst? Da steht eindeutig: *Man schreibt ein [verblasstes] Substantiv mit einer Präposition zusammen, wenn die Fügung zu einer neuen Präposition oder einem Adverb geworden ist.* Das heißt umgekehrt, wenn sie es (noch) nicht geworden ist, schreibt man nicht zusammen. Es gibt halt (noch) kein Adverb *zufuß*.

Comment: Du sagst quasi: wenn der Begriff zusammengesetzt als deutsches Wort existiert, dann schreib man ihn zusammen gesetzt (wenn nicht, dann nicht). Das geht daraus aber nicht hervor, dort steht nämlich noch **neu**. Ich verstehe das so, dass damit die (adverbiale oder präpositionale) Nutzung des Begriffs gemeint ist und sich aus dieser Nutzung die Zusammen- oder Getrenntschreibung ableitet.

Comment: So lese ich zumindest diese Regel. **Neu** bezieht sich für mich darauf, dass es sich nicht um eine "klassische" Präposition/Adverb handelt, sondern um eine, die sich gerade erst im Sprachgebrauch etabliert. Das passt auch zum Tenor dieser Regel, die ja im Prinzip nur das bestehende Durcheinander benennt. Andersherum ergebe es auch keinen Sinn, denn wenn **neu** im Sinne dieser Regel heißen sollte, dass der Schreiber die beiden Worte zusammenschreiben kann, so stünde da *wenn die Worte zusammengeschrieben werden können, werden sie auch zusammengeschrieben.* Und das ist ja nicht so.

Comment: Da kann ich nicht zu stimmen (und ich merke eben, dass ich den Titel meiner Frage irreführend gewählt habe). Der Name der Regel lautet **Präposition (Verhältniswort) und Substantiv**. Es ist also nicht gesagt, dass bei einer Komposition von den beiden Wortarten eine neue Präposition (oder eine adverbiale Konstruktion) entsteht, falls aber eine entsteht, dann kann man sie nach der Regel zusammenschreiben.

Answer (score 1):

> Man schreibt ein [verblasstes] Substantiv mit einer Präposition
>   zusammen, wenn die Fügung zu einer **neuen** Präposition oder einem
>   Adverb **geworden ist**.

Anstatt, inmitten und zuliebe sind komplett **neue** Wörter, die historisch durch Zusammenziehen einer längeren Wortgruppe entstanden sind und die man (heutzutage) nicht mehr ohne weiteres wieder trennen kann (*an Statt, *in Mitten, *zu Liebe). Insbesondere an dem -n in inmitt**en** ist das gut zu sehen, das in längeren Version gar nicht vorkommt ("in (der) Mitt**e**").

Anstelle, aufgrund, infrage, zugrunde und aufseiten befinden sich noch im Prozess der Zusammenziehung, d.h. sie werden getrennt immer noch verstanden *und benutzt*. Die tatsächliche Benutzung der Sprachgemeinschaft ist hier entgegen deiner Meinung durchaus entscheidend, denn die Regelformulierung sagt "**geworden ist**" (Perfekt = dieser Vorgang ist bereits passiert), nicht "**wird**" (Präsens = du kannst das in dem Moment halt so machen, wenn du willst).

Die Regel dokumentiert also die Schreibung der Wörter durch die Sprachgemeinschaft - statt sie dieser umgekehrt zu diktieren. Diese Konvention über die Schreibung kann sich allerdings natürlich weiter wandeln, und ich meine mich erinnern zu können, tatsächlich bereits über die Schreibung "zufuß" gestolpert zu sein. Prinzipiell steht es auch jedem frei, sie zu nutzen. Sie hat sich eben nur noch nicht großflächig durchgesetzt und wird daher vom Duden auch noch nicht anerkannt (und wahrscheinlich vom Deutschlehrer angestrichen).